# I don't think this question is a suitable close votes audit: it's asking too many questions for one

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

[why use std::ranges algorithms over regular algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/34115657)

It's clearly asking 4 questions.  So I was about to flag it "Requires Focus".

I did look at the question first and saw that 199K rep user had answered it.  I still felt that it required focus.

**Is the audit about being honest or toeing the line?**

Comment: All of those 4 questions seem to be very related and seem like they could basically be turned into one question.

Comment: I would suggest that if it's possible to have a discussion about what the question could be, or what it could mean then it is not a clear-cut question and hence unsuitable for an audit.  This isn't a discussion about whether the question should have been closed.  It's about it's suitability as an audit question.

Comment: The post requires an edit (there are almost no capital letters in the text) , yet IIRC that would have failed the audit. So it was inappropriate but for another reason.

Comment: Edited the original question, but it appears that the given answers each respond to a single particular one of those questions. I can certainly see the argument that the OP's post should be split. They didn't even get an answer to two of their four questions. Maybe they would have if they had asked each question independently, with links to the other related questions.

Comment: @VLAZ Editing a known good audit passes the audit, so that's not a problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33664424) is an example of a known-good audit that I passed by clicking Edit.

Comment: All the four "sub-questions" I've asked are related to the question that's in the title, and I think that a well written answer should address all of them. std::ranges is an important update to C++ library that isn't well covered in the community. That's why that this is an important question, and i did spend time trying to ask it properly, but I'm willing to accept the criticism. I want this question to be answered fully, and I am researching this topic in my free time to answer it myself in case no one else will.

Comment: now that my question is deleted, i have to say it's depressing seeing that SO goes away from being community-driven place, preferring strict rules for strict rules sake. i can provide plenty of examples of questions having similar "problem" that had valuable answers, except those were created over 5 years ago. in fact, it feels like all the good answers that contributed to sharing valuable knowledge that are not specific to just one subject were created long time ago. but if you have a question about something modern you better off searching countless blog posts that are very hard to navigate.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this is a bad question that needs focus (in fact, neither of the answers have addressed most of the things OP asked), and I will vote to close it as such when I have more votes again (I'm out for the day). Once it is closed, I am sure it will no longer be used as an audit.

Comment: IIRC a single close vote or downvote (both of which it now has) prevents CV audits.  It's not enough to prevent audits in all queues, though; some of the queues' criteria is unknown.